# How do I select some siblings but not all only via CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <ul class="cars">
      <li class="headline">My Cars</li>
      <li>Ferrari</li>
      <li>Hummer</li>
   </ul>
  <ul class="cars">
      <li class="headline">My Cars</li>
      <li>Volvo</li>
      <li>Caddilac</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to hide the second `<li class="headline">` with only CSS? I've tried several different sibling selector methods such as `+`, `>` etc.. but without success. I'm in a position where I have no control over the source code, only the CSS. So please do not suggest using javascript, changing the HTML etc. I simply can't change anything except the CSS :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `.headline` is always the first child of its containing `.cars`, so select siblings based on the `.cars` elements instead.

Most likely, you want the second `.cars`:

```
/* CSS2 */
.cars:first-child + .cars .headline {
    display: none;
}

/* CSS3 equivalent, but for browser compatibility just use the above instead */
.cars:nth-child(2) .headline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Great descriptive answer. Thanks!

Comment: There's another gotcha here, by the way: if you wanted the _third_ car and not the second one, then dynamic style updates for the headline would break in WebKit, because WebKit has broken `+` combinator support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the CSS3 selector nth-child:

```
div.wrapper ul.cars:nth-child(2) li.headline { display: none; }
```

Read more here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html

Comment: That doesn't quite work. `.cars:nth-child(2) .headline` works.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 have **nth-of-type()** selector but MSIE does not support it AFAIK.